# When trying to open a .blend file created on Mac on Windows, Blender always instantly crashes

Tags: blend-files

When I try to open a .blend file on my Windows, one I've created on my Mac, it opens up and a grey screen appears shortly. In the top left corner you can read the file path but then Blender crashes instantly. I've already tried multiple things, like downloading a new version or making sure that all textures used are in the same folders as the files themselves. But none of it really worked. I've read on the web, that it should be no Problem, as .blend files work on windows and Mac without problems. The file also is complete and didn't get hurt or corrupted, because it has been transferred safely via Cloud.

Comment: Is this just one file or all Blend files created on your Mac? If it happens with every file, perhaps you can create a simple file which crashes and share it here via https://blend-exchange.com/ so that we can have a look and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same crash.
In my case, it was because I created the .blend file with Blender 4.0 on mac, and tried to open it with Blender 3.1 on Windows.
Using 4.0 on windows fixed it.

This might not be what happened to you 2 months ago - but I ended up here with my problem, so maybe someone else will.